# WPF xaml objects from dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dynamic, reflection.emit

I am working on some kind of interoperability library and stuck with the following issue.

My interoperabilty library reflects classes from other language in a dynamic assembly with Emit. And no classes are available at the build time. When I try to put the dynamic assembly into XAML with something like this:

```
xmlns:test="clr-namespace:ClassesReflected;assembly=ClassesReflected"
```

and then get a class from there with this

```
<test:TestDelegate x:Key="dyn" x:Name="dyn"/>
```

I have an error at compile time.

Is there anyway to bypass the compile-time checks or load the xaml at runtime or anything else to make this solution working?

Any tips. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this works for you but there is one way.

First you need to define a namespace and ignore it:

```
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:validation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/ololo"
 mc:Ignorable="validation"
```

Then in code:

```
 [assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/  
 ololo", "SuperOlolo")]
```

Then you can use this namespace however you like:

```
 <validation:ValidationSummary Style="{StaticResource ValidationSummaryStyle}"
 Width="300" />
```

This will provide a clear build.

This method is used by Designer to read design-time peoperties.

I don't know if it can provide everything you need on run time may be some hacks will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does it really try to create anything, or ignore means that all this stuff is completely ignored during compilation?

Comment: I'm not sure about it but the fact is the Designer can use the properties defined in the ignored namespace. It can even assign DataContext to each element in a design time. So may be the Designer loads xaml somehow in his own way. The idea is to learn how the designer does it and may be this will help.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try in the next couple of days and let you know the result.

Comment: But doesn't "ignorable" just mean that the XAML processor will ignore the element?  And besides, even if it didn't, how would it know how to find the class if it has no namespace/assembly reference?

Comment: Have been looking through WPF extension API and nothing seems to be possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Btw, does anyone know how the references are resolved during xaml compilation? are references loaded as reflection-only?

Comment: @Daniel I doubt the runtime uses reflection.  You could consider using XamlReader to parse XAML strings at runtime.  Also, have you looked into ParserContext and XamlSchemaContext at all (not sure what they do, but they look vaguely promising)?

Comment: Vaguely promising is what they seem to be... Did't find anything useful there

Comment: @Daniel, what do you mean by saying it doesn't work?

Comment: 1. mc:Ignorable does not ignore objects if you put info about assembly. 2. If you don't put an assembly info, it fails on compiling generated .cs file saying there is no namespace like this. Second might have a workaround if there is a way to reference a dynamic assembly from a csproj, but I didn't find a way there...

Answer (score 0):

At least you could use a wrapper interface/class to make the members visible that you want to access in XAML.

Comment: The main idea is to avoid all this "wrappers" stuff. All classes are generated at runtime and are perfectly usable from C# code. There is no need for additional wrappers. Now the challenge is to make them visible in WPF/XAML.